# The sum of the reciprocal of squarefree numbers with an odd number of prime factors vs squarefree number with an even number of prime factors

Tags: sequences-and-series

We define $O\left( {{N^2}} \right)$ as :

the sum of the reciprocal of squarefree numbers less
than $(N+1)^2$ which has an odd number of prime factors,
where the prime factors are all less than or equal to $N$.

Similarly we define

$E\left( {{N^2}} \right)$ as :

the sum of the reciprocal of squarefree numbers less than $(N+1)^2$
which has an even number of prime factors, where the prime factors are all less than or equal to N.

Now consider

$O\left( {{N^2}} \right)- E\left( {{N^2}} \right)$

Can we have that $O\left( {{N^2}} \right)- E\left( {{N^2}} \right)$$ \ge 
$1  for $N>4$?

Example : $N=5$

$O\left( {{5^2}} \right)- E\left( {{5^2}} \right)$ =$$\left( {\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5}}} \right) - \left( {\frac{1}{{2 \cdot 3}} + \frac{1}{{2 \cdot 5}} + \frac{1}{{3 \cdot 5}}} \right) = \frac{{22}}{{30}}
$$

Comment: What have you tried?  A natural start might be to do a search, for as large $N$ as you can manage.  And...Is there context behind this?

Comment: I know that for  primorial ranges like $$\left( {\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5}} + \frac{1}{{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 7}} + \frac{1}{{2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7}} + \frac{1}{{3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7}}} \right) - \left( {\frac{1}{{2 \cdot 3}} + \frac{1}{{2 \cdot 5}} + \frac{1}{{3 \cdot 5}} + \frac{1}{{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7}}} \right) < 1
$$ It will always be less than 1. But this range is a lot shorter.

Comment: $N=5$ isn't a serious search.  Try much larger numbers, like all the $N$ up to $10^6$ or such.  Aside from possibly finding an example of what you want, you'll get good data on the functions involved, and that might enable you to make precise hypotheses, which can then be tested.  Keep in mind that many natural sounding questions in number theory are hard to resolve.

Comment: For research as @lulu is suggesting, use of the computer is probably mandatory.  This means that you will need at least moderate programming skills in a programming language like C, Java, or Python.  If you have never programmed before, then I suggest making Python your first (math oriented) programming language.  For what it's worth, in general, programming skills are extremely helpful, in a wide variety of ways, when attacking math problems.  One example is *sanity-checking* your analysis of a combinatorics problem.